# Huawei The splash ad is not closing

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated huawei ads kits in application. i have implemented as per the documentation. The app is not being open as it stucks in splash screen.
How to close the splash ad?

Answer (score 1):

We request you to please re-check the implementation of `onAdDismissed()` function of `SplashAdLoadListener`.

You need to navigate to next activity from the function, `onAdDismissed()` as shown below:

```
 SplashView.SplashAdLoadListener splashAdLoadListener = new SplashView.SplashAdLoadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Called when an ad is loaded successfully.
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Called when an ad fails to be loaded. The app home screen is then displayed.
        jump();
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdDismissed() {
        // Called when the display of an ad is complete. The app home screen is then displayed.
        jump();
    }
};
```